# Sultanas and raisins, I'm confused

Tags: meaning, etymology

Most Christmas pudding recipes call for both *sultanas* and *raisins*.

It is my understanding that a *raisin* refers to any dried grape.

A *sultana* is both the name of a seedless grape, originating from Smyrna in eastern Turkey, and the name of the raisin deriving from that grape.

I think Americans call them all *raisins* anyway, so that the Australian breakfast cereal *Sultana Bran* is known as *Raisin Bran* in the USA.

But I am still puzzled as to why recipes specify both sultanas and raisins. The sultanas are much nicer than the seeded raisins, and I can't think it would be to the detriment of the Christmas pudding if you included all sultanas.

And before some boring individual observes that 'this is off-topic because it is about cookery, not the English language', I would also be interested to know if the origin of *sultana* has anything to do with the wife or concubine of a *sultan*. The OED supplies nothing on etymology.

Comment: This [Britishfood](http://britishfood.about.com/od/glossary/ss/What-Is-The-Difference-Between-Raisins-Sultanas-And-Currants.htm) site spells it out.

Comment: @Edwin Some interesting stuff there.

Comment: There's a rather large list of differences in food & cooking terms between various English dialects at http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/67

Comment: even more confusing for non-brits, I would imagine...

Comment: @Joe That is quite a work.

Comment: @WS2 : we're just working on teasing out differences in the languages.  If you want something even more impressive, see [The Cook's Thesaurus](http://www.foodsubs.com/)

Comment: I am voting to close because (1) the first five paragraphs are, as the OP admits, about cookery and the OP's preferences. (2) Despite the OP's claim, the OED **does** give the etymology of *sultana*: thus there is a lack of research.

Answer (score 7):

From an American culinary perspective, while generally "sultana" and "raisin" are interchangeable, the unqualified sultana is a light-colored fruit and the unqualified raisin is a dark-colored fruit.

To rewrite this recipe using typical American English, replace "sultanas" with "golden raisins."

I would expect the recipe would be as easily understood in the UK if "raisins" were replaced by "dark sultanas;" however, this is contested in the comments below.

The issue of seeds is not relevant, as the vast majority of raisins are produced from the Thompson Seedless grape, including those known as sultanas. From [Raisin Grape Varieties](http://iv.ucdavis.edu/files/24430.pdf):

> ‘Thompson Seedless’ [grapes are] dominant in most commercial
>   raisin-producing countries worldwide.

However, the nomenclature issue is less clear-cut than I originally thought; the same book has this to say about the Thompson Seedless grape (emphasis mine):

> The variety’s most widely accepted name in the literature is
>   ‘Sultanina,’ a derivation of ‘Sultanieh,’ **believed by some to be a
>   recognition of a sultan’s appreciation for or ownership of the grape,
>   or of its possible origination in or near the town Soultanieh**, which
>   is situated in Persia not far from the Caspian Sea. Other synonyms are
>   ‘Oval Kechmish’ (Iran, Persia), ‘Kouforrogo’ (Greece), ‘Tchekirdeksiz’
>   (Turkey), and “Sultana” (Australia and South Africa).

There is another grape described near the end of the chapter as a "misnamed variety:"

> **"SULTANA"**
>
> The earliest introduction (mid-1800s) of this misnamed variety was by
>   a Mr. West, a Stockton nurseryman. It was distributed as “Sultana”
>   under the mistaken impression that it was the variety from which the
>   ‘Sultana’ raisins of commerce were produced. Colonel Agoston Haraszthy
>   also imported the same variety from Spain in 1861. It probably was
>   introduced into Europe from Asia Minor. It is described under the name
>   ‘Round Kishmish’ in French ampelographies, and should not be confused
>   with the true ‘Sultanina’ (Sultana) that we know as ‘Thompson
>   Seedless.’

Note that while this text addresses the origin of the name Sultanina, given to the grape variety I've been calling *Thompson Seedless*, it doesn't directly address the origin of the name Sultana, given to the dried fruit produced from that grape (and to an ostensibly unrelated grape variety).

Comment: Note that both dark and golden raisins are made from green (i.e. light-colored) grapes. The difference is that one is treated (usually with sulfur dioxide) to retain its light color, while the other is allowed to darken naturally.

Comment: "I expect the recipe would be as easily understood [in the UK] if you replaced 'raisins' with 'dark sultanas.'" Nope. In British usage, although it's true that a sultana is essentially a light raisin, you'd never use the phrase "light raisin" to mean a sultana, or "dark sultana" to mean a raisin.

Comment: @DavidRicherby But would you understand what ingredients were called for in the recipe?

Comment: @AirThomas Probably not, no. I'd think you were talking about some special kind of sultana that I couldn't find in any of the shops. It wouldn't occur to me that you were using a convoluted phrase for a simple thing, unless I had my lateral thinking hat on. I'd probably substitute regular sultanas.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Fair enough; I've noted your perspective in the answer. As far as the recipe goes, the reason to use both is probably just aesthetic (but I'm trying to stay away from giving a cooking.SE answer here). :)

Comment: @sgroves Not to mention that there are plenty of places (Scandinavia, for instance) where raisins are very common, while sultanas are a bit of a rarity. I’m sure you can get them in shops, but I personally can’t remember ever seeing them anywhere, and they’re certainly not something people buy as snacks. That’s only raisins. (Currants we don’t have at all. Or rather, according to the dictionary and the Internet, we do, called _korend_ … but I’ve personally never even heard that word, nor seen them anywhere. For all practical purposes, we don’t have them.)

Comment: To agree with @DavidRicherby, in the UK there are yellow, green and the most common golden sultanas, so if I saw a recipe with 'dark sultana' I would take it to mean the golden ones as the other kinds are lighter.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19685/discussion-on-answer-by-airthomas-sultanas-and-raisins-im-confused).

Answer (score 4):

AmE usage seems a bit "variable", but I think everyone in the UK recognizes the same distinction...

> **Raisins** are dried white grapes (pictured #**3** below).
>   They are dried to produce a dark, sweet fruit. The grapes used are usually Moscatel.
>
> **Sultanas** are also dried white grapes but from seedless varieties.
>   They are golden in color and tend to be plumper, sweeter and juicier than other raisins.
>    Also referred to as **Golden Raisins** in the US.
>
> **Currants** (#**1** below) are dried, black, seedless grapes.

[image]

<sup>Sources: [Text](http://britishfood.about.com/od/glossary/ss/What-Is-The-Difference-Between-Raisins-Sultanas-And-Currants.htm), [Picture](http://www.tis-gdv.de/tis_e/ware/trockfru/sultanin/188a.jpg)</sup>

That may not be the clearest possible picture (currants are usually *much* smaller than raisins). OED doesn't explicitly say *why* the usage arose, but the relevant definition *(in full **sultana raisin**)* is in the entry with the primary definition *wife (or concubine) of a **sultan***. So the etymology is undisputed, even if it's not clear exactly *how* the culinary sense came about.

Comment: [This Wikipedia photo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zante_currant#mediaviewer/File:Grape_Rasins_plus_Zante_Currants.jpg) shows the difference more clearly.

Comment: @Janus: Good find! That's *exactly* the difference I'd expect in the UK, but I'll stick with mine in the answer because it has all three side-by-side (and, usefully, *numbered*). I've only recently become aware that sultanas (which are imho the best) are significantly more expensive than the others. I guess I should have expected that.

Comment: Regarding the etymology bit (which has piqued my interest now), [Weekley’s etymological dictionary](http://bit.ly/1zq1w1W) has: “_Sultana raisin_ is a 19 cent. trade-name, but the word was also used of 18 cent. confections”, which sounds like _sultan_ was used a bit like _Turkish_ nowadays (as in Turkish delights), as just some more or less vague indicator of Middle Easternness. Possibly (?) sweets and confections were considered more of a women’s thing (men preferring a pipe and a brandy?), so the female _sultana_ was used? It’s a theory, anyway …

Comment: In US English, (1) are *currants*, (2) are *golden raisins*, and (3) are *raisins*.  (3) are by far the most common type found in stores and cooking; (1) and (2) are a bit harder to find.  The most common variety of grapes used for raisins sold in the US are Thompson seedless.   The term *sultana* isn't used and would be likely to confuse US speakers.

Comment: What @Nate said. Also, around these parts, seeded raisins went out of fashion many generations ago. A "raisin" is emphatically NOT expected to contain any seeds. (Also, I thought the EU was against food additives and preservatives. Golden raisins, no matter what you call them, don't stay all plump and golden without some chemical help, you know.)

Comment: @ruakh: Dang! This is what happens when I try to combine text from one source with a picture from somewhere else. I suppose I'd better have a *third* go at getting it right...

Comment: Since when (or where) are *currants* not a completely different fruit than grapes? (Except Zante currants, which are actually raisins made from tiny grapes.)

Comment: @PeterShor: Until you brought it up here, I'd never even *considered* the possibility that "dried currants" as used in cake-making might have started life as "blackcurrants" rather than being some kind of grape. I'm no expert on such matters, so all I can do is cite this paragraph [**What Are Currants?**](https://www.webmd.com/diet/difference-between-raisins-sultanas-currants)
 *Not to be confused with the **black currant**, which is a type of berry, **currants** are raisins made from **a specific type of grape** — Black Corinth. They are also called Zante currants or Corinth currants.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In America, we usually don't use anything called currants in buns (or other baked goods), so when I read about "currant buns" in British books, I just assumed they were real currants. I find it kind of disappointing they're just raisin buns made with tiny raisins.

Answer (score -1):

Crazy how wrong all these answers are. Sultanas are dried differently than raisins. Raisins are sun dried sultanas are diped in oil and acid and dried.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/418803)